# Parse error and no clue about the error

Tags: parsing, haskell, if-statement

I dont know what is wrong in the code below. 
The objective of this code is to give me a list of the indexes of a character in a list.

Example: `elemIndices 3 [1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,5]` means `[2,4,6]`

```
elemIndices' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
elemIndices' x [] = []
elemIndices' x l = reverse (listaind x l)

listaind :: Eq a => a -> [a] ->[Int]
listaind x [] = []
listaind x (y:ys) = if x == y then (length ys) : listaind x ys
```

Comment: What's the error? I think you might need to wrap the calls in the last line in parentheses, ie `((length (y:ys)) - 1) : (listaind x ys)`

Comment: the error continues. i tried your solution and it fails as well

Comment: Btw, `length (y : ys) - 1` is `length ys`.

Comment: error:  parse error on input (name of next function i have in the file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `if` is missing a corresponding `else`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way, and once your comfortable with recursion, try to do it as a fold

```
elemIndices :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
elemIndices = elemIndices' 0

elemIndices' :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [Int]
elemIndices' _ _ [] = []
elemIndices' idx s (x:xs) =
    if s == x
    then idx : elemIndices' (idx + 1) s xs
    else elemIndices' (idx + 1) s xs
```

Comment: i would, but i can't change the heading of the function. i mean, my professors gave me this heading "elemIndices' :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> [Int]" so i can't change it. i really would like to use a variable for the index, but i can't. thx for the tip anyway. :D

Comment: ohhh ok got it. a secondary function. thx for the tip as well :)